# List items and iterators: do either push back or iterators create copies of original data?

Tags: c++, list, iterator, push-back

Though I've a lot of experience as C Embedded Programmer, I'm actually not so skilled in C++. I'm implementing a parser in which `ItemsToBeFound` are pushed within a list.

It happens that some of these items (let's say **master items**) carry more information, so that some other items (**slave items**) need to refer to *master items* to retrieve those info. This link is done at population phase, without iterators.

This is the sequence of the actions:

1. I save the pointer to the *master item*, and push it to the list
2. I set specific pointer field `pReferenceItem` of the *slave item* so that it points to the *master item*
3. Later, I start the iteration through the list
4. I save parsed information to *master item*
5. When it comes to process *slave item*, I try accessing master item's field. **But it is unchanged!**
6. The pointer to *master item* during iteration is different from the original one, so the pointer contained in *slave item* points to the original (unchanged) data

Any suggestion about some special qualifiers I could use in order to force the iteration through the original data? Any obvious mistake in the way I issue lists and/or iterators?

Please note that I'm sure about what asserted in step #6 above, because I've watched pointers values using the debugger.

Here's the simplified code showing the described issue:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

std::list<ItemToBeFound> myList;

class ItemToBeFound
{
private:
public:
    /* ... */
    int specialDataToBeRetreived;
    ItemToBeFound *pReferenceItem;
    /* ... */

    ItemToBeFound( ItemToBeFound *ref )
    {
        pReferenceItem = ref;
        specialDataToBeRetreived = 777;
    }

    bool isMaster( void )
    {
        return ( pReferenceItem == NULL );
    }
}


void PopulateList( void )
{
    ItemToBeFound *masterItem = new ItemToBeFound( NULL /* no refItem */ );
    myList.push_back( *masterItem );

    ItemToBeFound *slaveItem = new ItemToBeFound( masterItem );
    myList.push_back( *slaveItem );
}

int main( void )
{
    // ...
    PopulateList();
    // ...

    /* Let's iterate and do something */
    std::list<ItemToBeFound>::iterator it = myList.begin();
    while( it != itemsList.end() )
    {
        if( it->isMaster() )
        {
            it->specialDataToBeRetreived = 42; /* In the real program I get the value after a parsing activity */
        }
        else /* it is a slave item */
        {
            it->specialDataToBeRetreived = it->referenceItem->specialDataToBeRetreived;

            /* But it doesn't work! */
            std::cout << "Updated special value: " << it->specialDataToBeRetreived << std::endl;
        }

        it++;
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

In the *"slave"* branch of the conditional, during iteration, I expect the `specialDataToBeRetreived` I set in reference object, but I keep obtaining 777 (the example value I set in the constructor):

```
Updated special value: 777
```

And the reason why I get this value is that, as shown by the debugger, the reference item in iteration phase has an **address different** from the original one, pointed by the slave item.

---

### The questions

- Why did this change occur?
- I was expecting that the pointer to my object was just **copied** to the list, like in many *list* implementation I've seen in my life. Does the `push_back` method of the `std::list` template perform a copy of the pointed object?

Comment: Please post a [MRE].  There are several reasons why the code in your question will not even compile, let alone run.

Comment: There are some things to mention here, but as already stated this code won't compile. 
1. You never actually set any member variables of your items.
2. It's easier to use a for loop with `for(auto & item : myList) {...}` and the compiler will create code similiar to your `while`-loop, which makes code mor readable
3. what is `MDMItemToBeFound`? This may be the source of your problem.

Comment: This was my first question. Not the best question of the world but not even the worse I've ever seen. After a meta-post it received 1 UV and 2DV. After today it received a revenge DV, I decided to improve it hoping it will recover its negative score (IMO undeserved). In the worst case I just improved its readability... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators do not copy anything. In C terms, they behave almost like pointers within array.

However, you do copy elements here:

```
void PopulateList( void )
{
  ItemToBeFound *masterItem = new ItemToBeFound( NULL /* no refItem */ );
  myList.push_back( *masterItem ); //copy of masterItem pointee

  ItemToBeFound *slaveItem = new ItemToBeFound( masterItem ); //initialized with masterItem, which does not point to the object stored in the list!
  myList.push_back( *slaveItem ); //copy of slaveItem pointee, also stores masterItem, but not object from the list

//slaveItem is leaked here, masterItem is only kept via slaveItem copy in the list
}
```

If you initialize objects like this, your slave objects never store pointers to objects in the list, but rather to the objects created with `new`.

---

Let's go step by step through the code (I'll be a rubber debugger here):

```
ItemToBeFound *masterItem = new ItemToBeFound( NULL /* no refItem */ );
```

You allocate an object on the heap (they don't have names, but let's call it `m1`) and a pointer on the stack called `masterItem`, so derefenced `masterItem` is exactly `m1`.

```
  myList.push_back( *masterItem );
```

[`std::list::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back) creates a copy of the argument given to it (I ignore move semantics - they are not used here). Notice what is the argument - dereferenced `masterItem` or `m1` as we called it before.
The copy of the object `m1` created by `push_back` will be called `m2`

So now we have the following (with `a->b` meaning *`a` points to `b`*):

```
masterItem->m1
myList->m2
```

Next line:

```
  ItemToBeFound *slaveItem = new ItemToBeFound( masterItem );
```

Here, you initialize `slaveItem` with new object on the heap - `s1`.

```
masterItem->m1
myList->m2
slaveItem->s1->masterItem->m1 (s1 points to masterItem, which points to m1)
```

Last one:

```
myList.push_back( *slaveItem );
```

Again, `push_back()` creates a copy of its argument on the heap (this copy will be called `s2`)

```
masterItem->m1
slaveItem->s1->masterItem->m1 
myList->m2
myList->s2->masterItem->m1
```

Eventually, you have:

- 4 objects on the heap: `m1`, `m2`, `s1` and `s2` (all of type `ItemToBeFound`)
- 2 objects on the stack: `masterItem` and `slaveItem` (both of pointer type)
- one object in the global area: `myList` (can be treated as stack object here)
- `m2` and `s2` are stored in `myList` and can be iterated over
- Both `s1` and `s2` have pointers to `m1`
- No slave object points to `m2`

Later on, when you run `mainFunction()`, object `m2` gets filled with data, but object `s2` is trying to retrieve data from `m1`, which wasn't filled with any valueable data.

---

It's hard to propose any solution without more info. One I'd use if I couldn't reorganize class structure would be to use `std::list<std::shared_ptr<ItemToBeFound>>` instead, which will keep your pointers safe, and only store `std::weak_ptr<ItemToBeFound> referenceItem` in slave objects (to avoid any circular dependecies and declare ownership clearly).

You could have `std::list<ItemToBeFound*>` and manage memory manually, but that's against modern C++ spirit and should be used with great care - flow can take more branches in C++ than in C and it's more difficult to track all of them to `delete` everything.

You could technically store in slave objects pointers to objects stored in the list (or even iterators to those), but that feels like a weird solution. You don't control those objects and you don't own them, so you shouldn't keep pointers to those.

Comment: Forgive the basic level question, but I need to be sure: are you saying that reason why  `masterItem != masterItem iterator` in my loop is that `push_back` performs a copy of the object pointed by `*masterItem` to the list?

Comment: Yes, it is, thank you. I'm going to modify the question title in order to  underline "push_back"'s behavior, because it was not clear to me and I think it could be helpful for other developers. In fact, in my previous experience custom list implementations always used to save pointers to objects. *PS:* I was actually wondering how could `list.erase` _delete_ pointers allocated to the heap before pushing them to the list... Well, it couldn't.